# Read PDF from Network Share in Unity / Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, network-share

I want to read a pdf from a network share like "//192.168.100.24/inetpub/TestShare/PDF_500kb.pdf" in Unity. In the editor i got no problems, but when I try to run it on Android, the path gets a leading slash and removes the double slashes. 
I tried it already with different combinations of slashes, also with the file:// preset.
Nothing works on Android, i simple make a

`File.ReadAllBytes(link);`

I tried to find solutions for some hours now, and i got no luck.

What am I missing?
Is it really not possible to load data from network shares within a unity android app?

EDIT: 
I tried it with WebClient, File.ReadAllBytes and with Unitys UnityWebRequest.Get

Comment: does it work if you add "file:" and call it as a url

Comment: nope that doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know about Mono, you can use `System.Net`.

```
using System.Net;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("192.168.100.24/inetpub/TestShare/PDF_500kb.pdf", "file.pdf");
}
File.ReadAllBytes("file.pdf");
```

Comment: that doesn't work, as android or unity puts always a leading slash in front of the url.
```GetPdfViaWebClient: System.Net.WebException: Could not find a part of the path "/192.168.100.24/inetpub/TestShare/PDF_500kb.pdf".```